# Is it possible to use the K++ initialization procedure that k-means uses in scikit/sklearn learn?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I was reading the documentation for [k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) and I saw that it uses [k++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) as initialization. Is it possible to use its k++ initialization function implemented in sci-py?

Reading their documentation I assume that the only way to do it is to use the K- means algorithm but then don't train any number of iterations, as in:

```
N = 1000 #data set size
D = 2 # dimension
X = np.random.rand(N,D)
kmeans = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=8, init='k-means++', n_init=1, max_iter=0)
ceneters_k_plusplus = kmeans.fit(X)
```

would that work or is there a direct way to use their library properly? (couldn't find it in their docs)

After some pain and blood I managed to get it to run (thought not 100% if its correct but it returns a numpy array):

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.cluster.k_means_
import numpy as np
#from ..utils.extmath import row_norms, squared_norm
from sklearn.utils.extmath import row_norms, squared_norm
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state

X = np.random.rand(10,3)
n_clusters = 4
random_state = None
random_state = check_random_state(random_state)
x_squared_norms = row_norms(X, squared=True)

centers = sklearn.cluster.k_means_._k_init(X, n_clusters, random_state=random_state,x_squared_norms=x_squared_norms)
print centers
```

Comment: I would peek at the function `_k_init` inside the k_means_.py file eg at: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py or around that, as I think there you end up with the default value for init ... but I may be wrong, and it is a private function ... so "properly" using would exclude that ;-)

Comment: running the above doesn't allow me to set iterations to zero. I guess its to be expected.

Comment: @Dilettant lol, at this point I don't care, anything that lets me use K++ is fine :P

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented in scipy. There's a pull request implementing it, but it stalled.
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4119

Answer (score 0):

I have done it from scratch:

```
import random
def initialize(X, K):`
    C = [X[0]]
    for k in range(1, K):
        D2 = scipy.array([min([scipy.inner(c-x,c-x) for c in C]) for x in X])
        probs = D2/D2.sum()
        cumprobs = probs.cumsum()
        np.random.seed(20)            # fixxing seeds
        #random.seed(0)               # fixxing seeds
        r = scipy.rand()        
        for j,p in enumerate(cumprobs):
            if r < p:
                i = j
                break
        C.append(X[i])
    return C

centroids = initialize(data,K)
```

Where:
"data" is your data points cloud (n row points, m column dimensions)
 and "K" is the number of centroids wanted (array with K rows and m dimensions). Each row will be a centroid

I fixed the seed to get always the same coordinate results (random initialization, but always the same)... you could change this.

I hope it helps :)